# g++ is not recognized even thought my PATH variable has been updated

Tags: windows, path

I'm at my wits end here. This is what I get when I type "echo %PATH%" into cmd:

```
C:\Users\user>g++
'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\user>echo %PATH%
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\Wind
owsPowerShell\v1.0\; C:\MinGW\bin\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\P
ython39\Scripts\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\
user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin; C:\MinGW\bin\;

C:\Users\user>
```

I've tried everything. Of course i'm using new cmd instances to check. Restarting doesn't work. I can go to the C:/mingw/bin directory and open g++ just fine with cmd once there. I've tried all the different formatting with the PATH variable: The 'C:' part, semi colon at end, backslash at end. No permutation works. You can see in the output above that both my user and system path have the correct directory for g++.

UPDATE: Ok I just tried updating only one user/system path at a time. I get the 'This app can't run on your PC dialogue' (windows 8.1) and at returns 'access denied' now. But when I run the cmd as admin it works!
But still VScode returns

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
Cannot create temporary file in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp; C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe\: Invalid argument
```

now

Comment: Why do you have a space between `;` and `C:`?

Comment: I will fix this and try then. Still doesnt work